# Attention Mechanism / Tensorflow Tutorials

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, attention-model

I am trying to improve my draft of attention mechanism code where I had basically an iteration of the decoder steps and and LSTM decoder cell getting a context vector at each step from an attention module:

```
post_activation_LSTM_cell = layers.LSTM(n_s, return_state = True)
output_layer = Dense(1)

s0 = Input(shape=(n_s,), name='s0')
c0 = Input(shape=(n_s,), name='c0')
s = s0
c = c0


outputs = []

input_tensor = Input(shape=(past_period,raw_dataset.shape[-1])) 

h = Bidirectional(LSTM(n_a, return_sequences = True))(input_tensor)

for t in range(preview_period):

    context = one_step_attention(h,s)

    s, _, c = post_activation_LSTM_cell(context,initial_state = [s, c])

    out = output_layer(s)

    outputs.append(out)





model=Model([input_tensor,s0,c0],outputs)
model.summary()
```

I found the implementation from the tensorflow tutorials much cleaner, but I don't see how the decoder is getting at each output step a different context vector from the bahdanau, it looks like the decoder is getting only one context vector, what am I missing???

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention

```
class BahdanauAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(BahdanauAttention, self).__init__()
        self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
        self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
        self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, query, values):
        # query hidden state shape == (batch_size, hidden size)
        # query_with_time_axis shape == (batch_size, 1, hidden size)
        # values shape == (batch_size, max_len, hidden size)
        # we are doing this to broadcast addition along the time axis to calculate the score
        query_with_time_axis = tf.expand_dims(query, 1)

        # score shape == (batch_size, max_length, 1)
        # we get 1 at the last axis because we are applying score to self.V
        # the shape of the tensor before applying self.V is (batch_size, max_length, units)
        score = self.V(tf.nn.tanh(
            self.W1(query_with_time_axis) + self.W2(values)))

        # attention_weights shape == (batch_size, max_length, 1)
        attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(score, axis=1)

        # context_vector shape after sum == (batch_size, hidden_size)
        context_vector = attention_weights * values
        context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)

        return context_vector, attention_weights


class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, dec_units, batch_sz):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.batch_sz = batch_sz
        self.dec_units = dec_units
        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(self.dec_units,
                                       return_sequences=True,
                                       return_state=True,
                                       recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
        self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)

        # used for attention
        self.attention = BahdanauAttention(self.dec_units)

    def call(self, x, hidden, enc_output):
        # enc_output shape == (batch_size, max_length, hidden_size)
        context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(hidden, enc_output)

        # x shape after passing through embedding == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim)
        x = self.embedding(x)

        # x shape after concatenation == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim + hidden_size)
        x = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1), x], axis=-1)

        # passing the concatenated vector to the GRU
        output, state = self.gru(x)

        # output shape == (batch_size * 1, hidden_size)
        output = tf.reshape(output, (-1, output.shape[2]))

        # output shape == (batch_size, vocab)
        x = self.fc(output)

        return x, state, attention_weights
```

Comment: https://github.com/neqkir/attention-mechanism

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the decoder is getting only one context vector. The `call` method of the decoder class only implements a single step of the decoder.

Further in the tutorial, there is for loop iterating over the target sentence at training time, and another loop is used for sampling at inference time.

Comment: Thanks @Jindřich,  
  
`for t in range(1, targ.shape[1]):

      # passing enc_output to the decoder

      predictions, dec_hidden, _ = decoder(dec_input, dec_hidden, enc_output)


      loss += loss_function(targ[:, t], predictions)


      # using teacher forcing

      dec_input = tf.expand_dims(targ[:, t], 1)`

decoder is being executed as a RNN cell basically at each step, many thanks